# How can I convert TIFF files of various dimensions to uniformly sized PDF files with page size 8.5″×11″ without losing quality?

Tags: perl, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, libtiff

Currently I'm trying to use Perl/ImageMagick and/or Ghostscript to convert scanned text documents stored as TIFFs into an 8.5″×11″ ([ANSI A “Letter” size](http://enwp.org/ANSI/ASME_Y14.1)) PDF file.

I've tried many of the ImageMagick filters with resize and still find that some files perfectly legible before are now illegible. Often these images are at 72 dpi and when converted to be 8.5″×11″, it ends up with something like 612×792 pixels. The original was 1700×2200; as you can see there are quite a bit of pixels lost in the re-size.

Should I be using something else besides resize? Could it be something like ImageMagick is reporting the image is 72 dpi when it's really something like 200 dpi? Would re-sampling the image into the highest dpi that would fit in the 8.5″×11″ area help?

Does anyone have any other options to ultimately create a PDF file with all pages being 8.5″×11″?

Comment: 72 is the default value supplied for DPI when the actual DPI isn't known. Don't rely on DPI, use the actual image size in pixels.

Comment: Is your goal to show the image at its original physical size, or to fill the page as much as possible?

Comment: Can you specify one of the commands you used?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To put the original TIFFs without resampling and loosing quality into uniformly sized PDF pages with dimensions of 8.5x11 inches?

Comment: 72 dpi was the large part of my issue. The goal is to fill as much area of 8.5x11 as possible. I'm basically trying to do a best fit print to a pdf file. Right now it looks promising to re-sample atm.

Comment: No, re-sampling definitely isn't the best way forward when you come from TIFF. Try my proposal to use LibTIFF's `tiff2pdf` utility (with exactly the parameters I give in my answer) and see the difference yourself...

Comment: Oh, and BTW: Ghostscript can do a lot of things. But it cannot convert from TIFF to PDF... (unless you find a *PostScript* program, which does the job and which Ghostscript could use as a helper utility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Mantra: 'Use the right tool for the job...')**

You possibly shouldn't use ImageMagick for the job, but rather LibTIFF's `tiff2pdf` commandline utility:

```
tiff2pdf          \
    -z            \
    -o output.pdf \
    -p letter     \
    -F            \
     input.tiff
```

`-z` is for (lossless) Zip/Flate compression.
`-o` defines the output filename.
`-p` sets the media size.
`-F` fills the page.

Comment: This does do what I need apparently version 3.92 of tiff2pdf does not handle -f as one might hope so using version 4.0.1 with -F looks great. Now with this problem solved i'll have to see how best to move a landscape to portrait prior to conversion to add the finishing touch.